# setMargin to fit bitmap dimensions

Tags: android, bitmap

How to use setMargin method to fit bitmap dimensions?
I can use `setmargin(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeigth(),...)`
or I need to convert the bitmap dimensions to dp?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This sets margin size in PIXELS, is not the same as the dpi unit in the xml of this question

Comment: I use this method on a canvas but I have an offset